# Why assigning and printing count from a query gives a different result in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Availability 
WHERE CONVERT(date, DayStartTime) = '9/1/2022 09:00 AM'
```

which returns a value of "1" in the SSMS query window.

But if I execute the following query, it prints "0"

```
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @DayStartTime datetime = '9/1/2022 09:00 AM'

SELECT @i = COUNT(*) 
FROM Availability 
WHERE CONVERT(date, DayStartTime) = @DayStartTime

PRINT @i
```

Any reason? Thanks!

**Update**

Changing the query like this works.

```
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @DayStartTime datetime = '9/1/2022 09:00 AM'
DECLARE @From DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, @DayStartTime)
DECLARE @To DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @From)

PRINT @From
PRINT @To

SELECT @i = COUNT(*) 
FROM Availability 
WHERE DayStartTime >= @From AND DayStartTime < @To

PRINT @i
```

Comment: What is the type of the `DayStartTime` column, and why are you converting to `DATE` while including a time? For date/time literals, prefer a [safe format](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe) rather than the ambiguous one you're using now, and compare using the actual type of the column, as this gives the best chance for using indexes. Of course, if you want to index date/time values your column had best be `DATE/DATETIME[2]` itself as well, not a string type.

Comment: datetime is the datatype.  I am converting to make sure it returns the results for the day part by ignoring the time part.

Comment: Best policy for indexability is to write date/time queries as `WHERE DayStartTime >= @From AND DayStartTime < @To`, with both `@From` and `@To` typed as `DATETIME` (or whatever the underlying type is), which you then set as necessary. In this case, if you only want a date, make that `DECLARE @From DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, '2022-09-01T09:00:00'); DECLARE @To DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, @From, 1)`. The `CONVERT(DATE, Column) = <Value>` operation happens to [not completely suck](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047), but is still not as good as a proper range.

Comment: (...and that should be `DATEADD(DAY, 1, @From)` of course.)

Comment: `WHERE DayStartTime >= CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, @DayStartTime)) AND DayStartTime < CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(date, @DayStartTime)))` would be the best way to write this query

Answer (score 0):

In this query:

```
select count(*) from Availability where Convert(date,DayStartTime)='9/1/2022 09:00 AM'
```

The constant becomes a date type at compile time because of the comparison the date expression, removing the time value. View the execution plan an you will see date literal '2022-09-01' without the time.

In contrast, the second query uses a strongly-typed datetime variable. The value is unchanged at compile time because datetime has a higher data type precedence than date. The date column will be converted to datetime so you will not get equality for times other than midnight.